# The algebraic elements of $K$ extension of $F$ are a subfield of $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra

the question I wanna try to answer is this:

> The algebraic elements of $K$ extension of $F$ are a subfield of $K$

I know that:

An element $a \in K$ is algebraic on $F$ if $f(a)=0$ for some polynomial $\not=0$. Let $S$ be the subfield of algebraic elements of K.  So as definition, $S \in K$ because $K$ is an extension of S too.  But if it's an algebraic extension, must be closed and of course finite.

My approach is that I have two algebraic elements $a,b \in K$. 
$a+b \in K$ and also $ab \in K$, and of course they belong to $S$ too.

Maybe I need to write a polynomial with the algebraic elements and show that is finite?

I've some difficult to glue together those pieces for a satisfying proof. Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove that $a \in K$ is algebraic over $F$ iff $[F(a):F]$ is finite iff $a \in L \subseteq K$ with $[L:F]$ finite. Then prove that $a,b \in K$ algebraic implies $[F(a,b):F]$ finite.

Comment: To prove the first I can write an $f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1 x+a_0$ with $a_i$ algebraic elements, so I have a set $L=\{  a_0,a_1,...,a_{n-1}\}$. This set is finite.  The solutions of the polynomial lives in $K$ for some $s$ solution(s) of $f(x)$. Then $K(s)$ is a subfield of algebraic elements of $K$. The second assertion is that if we repeat for a $b$, we have anothe extention that is finite, so the proof is complete. Any error?

Comment: I think that we could prove this also with a $f(x)$ composed of coefficient $a,b$ instead of the all $n-tuple$ set used previously. The idea is the same